# Trying to post a user's email address to a membership table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://github.com/jtrinker/highlands

I'm building an app that allows a user to sign in and join a group. When they click on a group and then click 'join' I would like the user's email address to be posted to the memberships table and the users that have joined that group be saved.

I have a User, Group, and Membership model. Things got a little hairy once I added the membership table.

Models:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible :user_email
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  attr_accessible :description, :location, :name
end
```

groups#show:

```
<h1><%= @group.name %></h1>
<h4><%= @group.location %></h4>
<p><%= @group.description %></p>
<%= link_to "Join +", memberships_path(:user_email => user.email), :method => :post %>
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to have a user become a member of a group.

All my code is up on github - https://github.com/jtrinker/highlands

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are sending :post request to groups#create action via link_to, but you can do this another way:

create :join action in Membership controller

```
def join
# some code here
end
```

add to route following code

```
resources :membership do
  get :join, via: :get
end
```

it show return route like:

```
membership_join GET /membership/:membership_id/join(.:format) membership#join
```

than in view link to join action with membership_id

```
<%= link_to "Join +", membership_join_path(:membership_id => @group.id) %>
```